# How to calculate the intersection of a line segment and circle with CGAL

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, cgal

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to understand how to use CGAL's Circular Kernel to calculate the intersection(s) between a line segment (Line_Arc_2) and a Circle (Circle_2). Unfortunately there isn't much in the way of example code for the Circular Kernel, and I'm not finding the reference manual much help.

Here is code that I thought would work, but right now it won't even compile (Mac OS 10.9 using the latest system compiler):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <CGAL/Exact_circular_kernel_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Circular_kernel_intersections.h>
#include <CGAL/intersections.h>
#include <CGAL/result_of.h>
#include <CGAL/iterator.h>
#include <CGAL/point_generators_2.h>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

typedef CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2        CircK;
typedef CGAL::Point_2<CircK>                 Pt2;
typedef CGAL::Circle_2<CircK>                Circ2;
typedef CGAL::Line_arc_2<CircK>              LineArc2;
typedef CGAL::cpp11::result_of<CircK::Intersect_2(Circ2,LineArc2)>::type Res;

int main(){
  int n = 0;
  Circ2 c       = Circ2(Pt2(1,0), Pt2(0,1), Pt2(-1, 0));
  LineArc2 l    = LineArc2( Pt2(0,-2), Pt2(0,2) );

  std::vector<Res> result;
  CGAL::intersection(c, l, std::back_inserter(result));

  return 0;
}
```

I get an error on the result_of line: "error: no type named 'result_type' in...", and a second error that "no viable overloaded '='" is available for the intersection line.

Also, since this would probably be the follow up question once this is working: how do I actually get at the intersection points that are put in the vector? CGAL's documentation suggests to me "result" should contain pairs of a Circular_arc_point_2 and an unsigned int representing its multiplicity. Is this what I will actually get in this case? More generally, does anyone know a good tutorial for using the Circular Kernel and Spherical Kernel intersection routines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that result_of doesn't work here, despite being suggested in the CGAL reference manual for the CircularKernel's intersection function.

Here is a different version that seems to work and can properly handle the output:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <CGAL/Exact_circular_kernel_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Circular_kernel_intersections.h>
#include <CGAL/intersections.h>
#include <CGAL/iterator.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2        CircK;
typedef CGAL::Point_2<CircK>                 Pt2;
typedef CGAL::Circle_2<CircK>                Circ2;
typedef CGAL::Line_arc_2<CircK>              LineArc2;
typedef std::pair<CGAL::Circular_arc_point_2<CircK>, unsigned> IsectOutput;

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int n = 0;
  Circ2 c       = Circ2(Pt2(1.0,0.0), Pt2(0.0,1.0), Pt2(-1.0, 0.0));
  LineArc2 l    = LineArc2( Pt2(0.0,-2.0), Pt2(0.0,2.0) );

  std::vector<IsectOutput> output;

  typedef CGAL::Dispatch_output_iterator< CGAL::cpp11::tuple<IsectOutput>, 
                      CGAL::cpp0x::tuple< std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<IsectOutput> > > > Dispatcher;
  Dispatcher disp = CGAL::dispatch_output<IsectOutput>( std::back_inserter(output) );

  CGAL::intersection(l, c, disp);

  cout << output.size() << endl;
  for( const auto& v : output ){
    cout << "Point: (" << CGAL::to_double( v.first.x() ) << ", " << CGAL::to_double( v.first.y() ) << "), Mult: " 
     << v.second << std::endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`result_of` is working but the operator you are asking for does not exist, you are missing the output iterator.
However, I agree the doc is misleading. I'll try to fix it.

The following code is working fine:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <CGAL/Exact_circular_kernel_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Circular_kernel_intersections.h>
#include <CGAL/intersections.h>
#include <CGAL/result_of.h>
#include <CGAL/iterator.h>
#include <CGAL/point_generators_2.h>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

typedef CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2        CircK;
typedef CGAL::Point_2<CircK>                 Pt2;
typedef CGAL::Circle_2<CircK>                Circ2;
typedef CGAL::Line_arc_2<CircK>              LineArc2;
typedef boost::variant<std::pair<CGAL::Circular_arc_point_2<CircK>, unsigned> > InterRes;
typedef CGAL::cpp11::result_of<CircK::Intersect_2(Circ2,LineArc2,std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<InterRes> >)>::type Res;

int main(){
  Circ2 c       = Circ2(Pt2(1,0), Pt2(0,1), Pt2(-1, 0));
  LineArc2 l    = LineArc2( Pt2(0,-2), Pt2(0,2) );

  std::vector<InterRes> result;
  CGAL::intersection(c, l, std::back_inserter(result));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Updating the doc would be most helpful!